# Reading an arraylist Objects and their fields in another class(java)

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to make a user login system at the moment and i need help on reading objecs and their fields of an existing arraylist in another class in order to authenticate.Belowis the code for the object constructor,

```
public class User {
    public String UserName ;
    public String UserSurname ;
    public String UserUsername ;
    public String UserPassword ;
    public int UserType ; // 0 for cashier 
                          // 1 for manager

public User() {}

public User(String UserName, String UserSurname, String UserUsername, String UserPassword, int UserType) {
    this.UserName = UserName;
    this.UserSurname = UserSurname;
    this.UserUsername = UserUsername;
    this.UserPassword = UserPassword;
    this.UserType = UserType;
}
/* 
Getters and Setters
*/
```

Here is my "database " of users and itemlist (**Note**-I have a constructor for these obj)

```
public class DataBase {
    ArrayList<User> userlist;
    ArrayList<Item> itemlist;


    public DataBase(){
        User user1 = new User("example","example","example","example",1) ;
        User user2 = new User("sda","fas","gdf","vcx",0) ;
        User user3 = new User("htr","ytr","vxc","xaxxzx",0) ;
        User user4 = new User("dag","gdf","dfgfgd","thrhf",0) ;

        ArrayList<User> userlist = new ArrayList<User>();
        userlist.add(user1);
        userlist.add(user2);
        userlist.add(user3);
        userlist.add(user4);

        ArrayList<Item> itemlist = new ArrayList<Item>() {};
        Item item1 = new Item(1,"sadas",25.0) ;
        Item item2 = new Item(1,"dcxz",25.0) ;
        Item item3 = new Item(1,"czx",25.0) ;
        Item item4 = new Item(1,"zxccxz",25.0) ;
        Item item5 = new Item(1,"czx",25.0) ;
        Item item6 = new Item(1,"tertgdf",25.0) ;
        Item item7 = new Item(1,"zxcfes",25.0) ;
        Item item8 = new Item(1,"erwt",25.0) ;
        Item item9 = new Item(1,"gfdvcx",25.0) ;
        Item item10 = new Item(1,"hjfgh",25.0) ;
        itemlist.add(item1);
        itemlist.add(item2);
        itemlist.add(item3);
        itemlist.add(item4);
        itemlist.add(item5);
        itemlist.add(item6);
        itemlist.add(item7);
        itemlist.add(item8);
        itemlist.add(item9);
        itemlist.add(item10);
    }

    public DataBase(ArrayList<User> userlist, ArrayList<Item> itemlist) {
        this.userlist = userlist;
        this.itemlist = itemlist;
    }
    public ArrayList<User> getUsers() {
        return userlist;
    } //end get Users

    public ArrayList<Item> getItems(){
        return itemlist;
    } //end get Items
} // end class
```

And here is what i have done to read from the ArrayList i showed above .. :

```
String username = UsernameField.getText();
        String pass = PasswordField.getText();

        try
        {   

        users = new DataBase();
        ArrayList<User> userlist = users.getUsers();           
        for(User d : userlist){
        if(d.getUserUsername() != null && d.getUserUsername() == username && d.getUserPassword() != null && d.getUserPassword() == pass){
        Succed success = new Succed();
        success.setVisible(true);
        }
        else {
            failure fail = new failure() ;
            fail.setVisible(true);
        }
            }// end for 
        }/* end try  */ catch (NullPointerException ex) {
        }
```

I would appriciate if someone could help me to solvet this.I've spent a lot of time trying to solve this problem.

The Action Listener code :

```
LoginButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            LoginButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
```

Comment: as a sidenote, i´d suggest to use a `Enum` instead of an `int` to identify if the user is a cashier or a manager.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: When do you populate the two lists in _DataBase_ ?

Comment: Hello @Berger thank you for comment , checck the code again , i added the list population

Comment: @KevinEsche thank you for your support , latter when i implement other classes i might change that , but at the moment need help with this :/

Comment: @KevinEsche I cant find an correct answer in the post you mentioned , becouse i need to compare the String from the text field and passwordfield with the objects username and their  passwords ,

Comment: @HasS you are comparing the references of the String values, and not the value of the `String` itself. If you compare `Objects` then you need to use the `equals` method.

Comment: @KevinEsche I understand , d.getUserUsername().equals(username)  is what i will  use ,  but i need to know , is the code for reading my DataBase objects acceptable , or my mistake is on that part of code??

Comment: @HasS I found a missing line in your question `public Database(){` This was quite misleading as I had to figure out the code using the braces.

Comment: @VamshiKrishnaAlladi code edited :) now i only need to understand how to make the login works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One should never compare strings for equality using `==`, instead make use of `.equals()`. `==` compares the references not the contents of the string variables. For comparison of contents `.equals()` or `.equalsIgnoreCase()` should be used based on the requirement.

For reference see [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals(java.lang.Object))

**Update:**

Right now you are running a loop on userlist and checking if the entered username is in the list. Instead do it like this:

```
Succed success = new Succed();
failure fail = new failure();

for(User d : userlist){
    if(d.getUserUsername().equals(username) && d.getUserPassword().equals(pass)){
        success.setVisible(true);
        break;
    }
}

if(!success.isVisible()){
    fail.setVisible(true);
}
```

assuming `isVisible()` is defined on class `Succed` which return `true` if the success is set to visible and return `false` in other case.

Comment: Right on. In his case, something like this: `if(d.getUsername() != null && d.getUsername().equals(username) && d.getPassword() != null && d.getPassword().equals(pass))` ...

Comment: Just `if(username.equals(d.getUsername()) && pass.equals(d.getPassword()))` would do, As `.equals()` method implicitly does the "not `null`" validation.

Comment: @VamshiKrishnaAlladi I changed that part of code but the part of code when i read the DataBase objects is part of an action listener button (login ) and when i click it , it does nothing ... maybe the code when i try to read the objecs is wrong ??...

Comment: @HasS can you post the code of the action listener?

Comment: @VamshiKrishnaAlladi you are presuming `username` is not null.

Comment: @VamshiKrishnaAlladi LoginButton.setText("Login");
        LoginButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                LoginButtonActionPerformed(evt);    }
        });

Comment: @vikingsteve my bad. its actually the reverse of that. I was thinking the value `username` is from DB and other one as the value from text field. so the code would be `if(d.getUsername().equals(username) && d.getPassword().equals(pass))`.

Comment: @HasS can you update the Question itself with your code related to action listener. so that it would be more readable. also if you can, include the `LoginButtonActionPerformed()` code as well.

Comment: Is the 3rd snippet the code for the `LoginButtonActionPerformed()`?

Comment: Yes , i think everything is fine about that code  , check it out ive updated the question @VamshiKrishnaAlladi

Comment: @VamshiKrishnaAlladi well in that case you are assuming `d.getUsername()` and `d.getPassword` are not null... ;)

Comment: @HasS try replacing `catch (NullPointerException ex) {
        }` with `catch(Exception e){ e.printStackTrace();}`, also modify the condition check with `if(d.getUsername().equals(username) && d.getPassword().equals(pass))`.

Comment: @vikingsteve yes I am assuming the values in DB are not `null`. correct me if I am wrong @HasS

Comment: in this case debug console  prints error : 
 java.lang.NullPointerException
 at View.GuiLogin.LoginButtonActionPerformed(GuiLogin.java:146)
 at View.GuiLogin.access$000(GuiLogin.java:17)
 at View.GuiLogin$1.actionPerformed(GuiLogin.java:50) @VamshiKrishnaAlladi

Comment: @HasS I have a question for you.

Comment: @VamshiKrishnaAlladi yes , the values in DB are not null

Comment: check what line number 146 in GuiLogin.java is.

Comment: @VamshiKrishnaAlladi   for(User d : userlist){  // line 146

Comment: Just before the for each loop can you verify if userlist is not null.

Comment: @VamshiKrishnaAlladi i wrote a if statement before "for " loop like this if(userlist != null) 
        for(User d : userlist){ 
in this case when i click button it does nothing , and it does not print any error in debug console

Comment: so your `user.getUsers()` is returning null. check if you are initializing your DB properly? I mean check what your DB constructor is doing.

Comment: All my DB code is on my post , can you check it and tell me what is missing? Becouse I have no idea what I did wrong @VamshiKrishnaAlladi

Comment: what is the constructor doing? add that code also to the question.

Comment: @VamshiKrishnaAlladi i added the constructor to the code , anyway i dont understand ur question , is there any way to send you everything i've done so far?

Comment: [Just for sake of mentioning] basically you were re-declaring the userlist and itemlist values in constructor. that is why the return value from getter is null.

Comment: Problem solved .. ! thank you a lot for your useful help !